# How to send data in ListView dynamicaly in android.?

Tags: android-layout

My question is how do i send data written in EditText of dialogue box by clicking button and display it on LIstView of Main Activity. ?

```
public class TaskDetailsActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    String[] timepass= new String[100];


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.taskdetails);
            //timepass[0] = "sidd";
            /*ListView tasklist= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.insideaddtask, R.id.tp, timepass);
            tasklist.setAdapter(adapter);*/
    }
    public void addnewtask(View view)
    {
            showDialog(1);
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
    {
            Dialog dialog=null;
            switch (id) 
            {
            case 1:        dialog = new Dialog(TaskDetailsActivity.this);
                            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.addtask);


                            Button task_add_ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_ok);
                            task_add_ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
                            {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View arg0)
                                    {
                                            EditText writetask = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_writetask);
                                            String data = writetask.getText().toString();
                                            timepass[0] = data;
                                    }
                            });
                    break;

            default:
                    break;
            }
            return dialog;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use any adapter for this arrayadapter of type string...

and use the button's onclick method to populate the listview...

below link provides a good example...

http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296

www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-listview-tutorial/